# Query runs faster in SQL Server than via ADO.NET command being sent

Tags: c#, t-sql, ado.net, database-performance

So I have the following in my CRUD method in my DL which brings back a photo blob:

```
    public static MemberPhoto RetrievePhoto(string customerID)
    {
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(Config.DbConnectionString);

        using (DbCommand cmd = db.GetSqlStringCommand(string.Format(@" SELECT  customerID,
                                                                                p.Photo as PhotoBlob

                                                                         FROM 
                                                                         SomeTable t

                                                                         WHERE 
                                                                         t.PhotoID = (SELECT MAX(t.PhotoID) FROM SomeTable t
                                                                                      WHERE t.customerID = @{0} 
                                                                                      GROUP BY t.CustomerID)", "customerID")))
        {
            try
            {
                db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@customerID", DbType.String, customerID);

                using (IDataReader reader = db.ExecuteReader(cmd))
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Photo photo = new Photo();
                        photo.LoadFromDataReader(reader);
                        return photo;
                    }
                }
            }
```

so that runs about 10 seconds slower than if I run this straight from management studio:

```
SELECT  customerID,
    t.Photo as PhotoBlob

    FROM 
    SomeTable t

    WHERE 
    t.PhotoID = (SELECT MAX(t.PhotoID) FROM SomeTable t
              WHERE t.customerID = '0000900595555' 
              GROUP BY t.CustomerID)
```

I don't know if it's because it takes a while for the reader to read the blob and bring that back or what?  If that's the problem how do you speed this up?  its instant at the DB, I run that query and it's a millisecond result timing.

UPDATE:

more info; the field type in the table is type Image in SQL Sever for that BLOB.

I also ran my Unit Test, same amount of time, even after it hits my LoadFromReader:

```
[Test]
public void GetMemberPhoto_ByContractNumber_ReturnsAValidMemberPhoto()
{
    // Arrange
    const string customerID = "0044664176";

    // Act
    DTO.MemberPhoto memberPhoto = MemberPhotoCRUD.RetrieveMemberPhotoFromBlob(customerID);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(memberPhoto);
    Assert.IsTrue(memberPhoto.CustomerID > 0);
    Assert.IsNotNull(memberPhoto.PhotoBinary.Length > 0);
}
```

Comment: Hmm... This really isn't an apples to apples comparison. Even still, there is some information you really should provide. (1) What is the datatype of your DB column, "Photo"? (2) How many records are being returned in your test?

Comment: only one record is being returned at all times since I am doing a Max.  It's milliseconds in Management Studio when I run this same query.

Comment: how is this apples to oranges?  You talking about the query cause the query is exactly the same query runnning it either way (from .NET or from SQL Management Studio, it's the same query being run)

Comment: I'm referring to running a query directly on the database versus making a database call in code. A 10 second difference is not typical/normal, but without knowing the size and type of data being returned, it's hard to guess where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Did you try and profile your database to see if there are any difference in the time consumed by the query in the database...? This will at least rule out the database as the problem (or confirm that it in fact is).

Comment: @Jan how would I profile the database, I mean like Marc said, running a query in SQL Management Studio isn't the same as running it from .NET because it's actually working with and brining back the BLOB from .NET but not in SQL Management Studio (as it's just listing it in the search results, not pulling the BLOB into some stream)

Comment: Your could attach the SQL Server Profiler to your database and follow interactions between your application and SQL Server. This can be a real eyeopener when it comes to actual workload on the database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a blob of the image. SSMS doesn't actually get all the data - it truncates large values of `[n][text]`, `[n][varchar](max)`, `image` and `varbinary(max)`, since you're usually not directly using those results. It sounds like this is therefore a bandwidth issue. Check the size of the blob - if it is insanely large, this is likely.

Other possibilities for unusual performance:

- different isolation level
- different `SET` options
- parameter sniffing

Also - the comment about `string.Format` is correct; it isn't doing you any *harm*, but it isn't serving any useful purpose either. Personally I'd just write `@customerID` directly into the query. Otherwise it is like `string.Format("this and {0}", "that")` - you might as well just use `"this and that"`.

It could also be that processing the image back at the client is slow. For this to be a direct comparison, you would need to just get the data as (say) a `byte[]`. Your SSMS comparison doesn't process the data into a `Photo` object. It could be that *this* is the slow operation, so I would profile `photo.LoadFromDataReader(reader)`.

Comment: yea I get your point about the string.format.  It was just something CodeGened.

Comment: I just checked the type for that blob is Image in the SQL Table.  I also just deployed this to their dev server, same response time.  I don't think their dev server or the server holding these fields are the beefy or not but I'll find out about the source server running SQL Server and see if that's causing latency or not possible...??

Comment: but again it's not the load from DataReader and I am doing a GetByte.  this lag happens from the time the cmd is sent to the time it gets back from SQL server, before it steps into LoadFromDataReader

Comment: I'm starting to notice that even if it doesn't find a blob, that query takes a long time to come back to my CRUD method....so not sure what the heck is causing the delay now, especially if that sql call is not finding a record in some cases but still lags the same amount of time.

Comment: @user1808194 have you checked the things I mentioned in the bullet points? actually, I'd start with the last one (parameter sniffing) - try adding `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` to the query (and the sub-query). Also just check the query in terms of indexing etc.

Comment: @user1808194 and re the line-breaks - that is a feature of the `@" ... "` verbatim string literal (the leading `@` being important) - nothing to do with `string.Format`

Comment: where do I add that, in the query after the final where clause?

Comment: yea nevermind Marc about the line breaks, dumb reply I had which is why I removed it

Comment: trying to get syntax string.Format(@"  SELECT  customerID,
                                                                                    p.Photo as PhotoBlob
                                                                            FROM SomeTable t
                                                                            WHERE p.PhotoID = (SELECT MAX(p.PhotoID) FROM SomeTable p WHERE p.customerID= @{0} 
                                                                            GROUP BY t.customerID )  option (OPTIMIZE FOR (@{0} UNKNOWN))", "customerID")))

Comment: crap still not right: string.Format(@"  SELECT  customerID,
                                                                                    t.Photo as PhotoBlob
                                                                            FROM SomeTable t
                                                                            WHERE t.PhotoID = (SELECT MAX(t.PhotoID) FROM SomeTable t WHERE t.customerId = @{0} 
                                                                            GROUP BY t.customerID ) OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)", "customerID")))

Comment: EL could be doing something weird as well. I don't really like Enterprise Library, that was ok when there was no connection pooling but now, I don't see a reason to be using it.

Answer (score 1):

The select is wrong.  Do not use string.Format and change  `WHERE t.customerID = @{0}` to `WHERE t.customerID = @customerID`.

Now comment out the `photo.LoadFromDataReader(reader);` and run your test.  If the time is close to management studio's then the issue is in your LoadFromDataReader method.

Comment: why not use string.format?  I've seen that done 1000 times at .coms I've worked at

Comment: the issue isn't load from reader because the timelapse happens before the load from reader...it's taking 10 seconds BEFORE it gets to the loadfromreader line

Comment: that string.format has nothing to do with performance.  It's just replacing text BEFORE the sql command is even sent to the server.  The call doesn't even happen until the ExecuteReader command when THEN is where it makes the sql call and from that point to when it makes the call to where it comes back to the line hoto.LoadFromDataReader(reader); is where the lag is.  Again it doesn't lag inside LoadFromDataReader, it lags between the invocation of the sql command (Sending it to the DB) and coming back.